# fs.readdir not reading files extracted to a local directory (function not even running)

Tags: javascript, node.js, lambda

I have extracted zip files to a local directory within my lambda function however fs.readdir function is not working and is also not returning an error. I think maybe I have a syntax error with the way I set up the function to run asynchronously.

```
    // Make Directories for Zipped and Unzipped files
    try {
        const zipDirFolder = await mkdirp(localZippedFolder, { recursive: true });

        const unZipDirFolder = await mkdirp(localUnzippedFolder, { recursive: true });
        console.log(unZipDirFolder);

    // Download files from s3 Bucket
        let newFolder = await s3.getObject(params).promise()
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        });
        const newZipFile = newFolder.Body; 

    // Extract files from zipped folder and store them in a local directory
        let filezFolder = await fs.createReadStream(params.Key)
        .pipe(unzipper.Extract({path: unZipDirFolder}));
        console.log(unZipDirFolder);

    // Read Contents of that local directory    
        await fs.readdir(unZipDirFolder, function (err, files) {
            if (err) {
                console.log('THERE WAS AN ERROR:' + err);
            } else {
                console.log(files);
            }
        });
}
```

Problem: fs.readdir is not running nor is it returning an error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a problem is in this statement:

```
let filezFolder = await fs.createReadStream(params.Key)
    .pipe(unzipper.Extract({path: unZipDirFolder}));
```

`fs.createReadStream().pipe()` does not return a promise.  So using `await` on it doesn't do anything useful.  So, you have not waited until the `.pipe()` is done.  Thus, you are calling `fs.readdir()` before the unzip operation is done.

At the moment, streams are not particularly promise-friendly.  You will probably need to register for some sort of event on the resulting stream that indicates when your unzip operation is done and then do the `fs.readdir()` from within that event handler.  I don't know your unzip library myself to know which event or how to best monitor it for completion.

Since `.pipe()` return a writable stream, you can probably do this:

```
fs.createReadStream(params.Key)
    .pipe(unzipper.Extract({path: unZipDirFolder}))
    .on('finish', () => {
         fs.readdir(...)
    }).on('error', (err) => {
         // error handling here
         console.log(err);
    });
```

---

Here's a simple little stand-alone program that shows the concept I'm talking about:

```
const unzipper = require('unzipper');
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;
const path = require('path');

const inputZip = path.join(__dirname, "zip", "photos.zip");
const outputZipDir = path.join(__dirname, "zip-output")

function run() {
    fs.createReadStream(inputZip)
        .pipe(unzipper.Extract({ path: outputZipDir }))
        .on('finish', async () => {
            let files = await fsp.readdir(outputZipDir);
            console.log(files);
            // use the files here
        }).on('err', err => {
            console.log(err);
    });
}

run();
```

The setup for this program is to put `photos.zip` into a `zip` subdirectory from where this program is run and to create a `zip-output` subdirectory from where this program is run for the unzipped files to go.

---

And, here's a promisified version that uses the same setup:

```
const unzipper = require('unzipper');
const fs = require('fs');
const fsp = fs.promises;
const path = require('path');

const inputZip = path.join(__dirname, "zip", "photos.zip");
const outputZipDir = path.join(__dirname, "zip-output")

// returns a promise that resolves/rejects when the unzip operation is done
function unzip(inputZip, outputDir) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.createReadStream(inputZip)
            .pipe(unzipper.Extract({ path: outputDir }))
            .on('finish', resolve)
            .on('err', reject);

    });
}

async function run2() {
    await unzip(inputZip, outputZipDir);
    let files = await fsp.readdir(outputZipDir);
    console.log(files);
}

run2().catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: so what would be the best way to go about making it return a promise so that it has enough time for the pipe to finish?

Comment: @brycent - i added an event handler mechanism for monitoring the pipe operation.  You could manually promisify this structure if you really want to use promises with it.

Comment: ah thanks, I am really having trouble visualizing it, would you be so kind as to send me a code example. thanks

Comment: @brycent - Visualizing what?  I've shown you how to use event handlers to monitor completion.

Comment: @jfriend001 I tried giving it a go and still it did not actually run the function. I am using the library "unzipper" however I am open to switching libraries if you believe there is one better used for this type of solution.

Comment: @brycent - I wrote a stand-alone program that demonstrates how to use the events I've referenced to know when the unzipping is done and then list those files.  I've added this program to the end of my answer.  If you follow the documented setup, you should be able to run this program yourself to see it work.

Comment: @brycent - I added a promisified version that wraps a promise around the unzipping.

Comment: I am still running into issues is there any way I could demonstrate to you what the entire lambda function looks like it would probably help in the context of solving this.

Comment: @brycent - Perhaps you should post a new question that shows the entire code context.  I think I've answered what you originally asked and showed here.  If you're having difficulties elsewhere in the code, please post a new question with ALL the relevant code and describe exactly what error you are getting or what wrong result you are getting.  If I'm online when you post it, I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because you'r trying to `await` fs.readdir and at the same time trying to callback. You shouldn't do both. Try removing the await or setting your lambda function `async` and remove the callback.

```
//Using await (Don't forget to place this in a async function)
const res = await fs.readdir(yourFilePath);

//Using Callbacks
fs.readdir(yourFilePath, (err, files) => {
  if (err) {
      console.log('THERE WAS AN ERROR:' + err);
  } else {
      console.log(files);
  }
});
```

Or you could use `fs.readdirSync` and do

```
const res = fs.readdirSync(yourFilePath)
```